# Override get_FIELD_display method in Django model

Tags: django

Let's say I have a field called `field` in my model, with a `choices` parameter defining the values to be returned by the `get_field_display` method.

I need the `get_field_display` method to return a different value based on another field. Is there any way to override `get_field_display`?

This doesn't work:

```
def get_field_display(self):
    if self.other_field == 1:
        return 'Other value'

    return super.get_field_display(self)
```

Comment: You could also write your own function for this...

Comment: But then I'd have to replace all instances where get_field_display is called.

Comment: If you define the function inside your model definitions, it would be the same as replacing get_foo_display...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: override get\_FOO\_display()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924985/django-override-get-foo-display)

Comment: Worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64436316/538284

Answer (score 4):

You can't call `super` because the function is defined not by the parent class but by the `ModelBase` metaclass. Try with this:

```
def get_field_display(self):

    if self.other_field == 1:
        value = 'Other value'
    else:
        field_object = self._meta.get_field('field')
        value = self._get_FIELD_display(field_object)

    return value
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I even tried with an override that only prints a string and the code is not even executed. I'm using Django 1.3.0.

Comment: How are you checking this? Did you open a Django shell, retrieved an instance of your model, and call its `get_field_display()` to see what's being returned?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. I also added a print statement at the beginning of the method but don't see anything printed in Django's log.

Comment: @Chewie this worked for me. This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a different function in the same model, then monkey patch it. For example, in admin.py you may do something like:

`ClassName.get_field_display = ClassName.get_patched_field_display`

It's not very 'nice' but it works for me.