# Django: override get_FOO_display()

Tags: python, django

In general, I'm not familiar with python's way of overriding methods and using super().

question is: can I override `get_FOO_display()`?

```
class A(models.Model):
   unit = models.IntegerField(choices=something)

   def get_unit_display(self, value):
     ... use super(A, self).get_unit_display()
```

I want to override get_FOO_display() because I want to pluralize my display.

But `super(A, self).get_unit_display()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally you would just override a method as you have shown. But the trick here is that the `get_FOO_display` method is not present on the superclass, so calling the `super` method will do nothing at all. The method is added dynamically by the field class when it is added to the model by the metaclass - see [the source here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L253) (EDIT: outdated link as [permalink](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8aad3321ed6f0b603361767a4fe00d046b5fdd34/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L742-L744)).

One thing you could do is define a custom Field subclass for your `unit` field, and override `contribute_to_class` so that it constructs the method you want. It's a bit tricky unfortunately.

(I don't understand your second question. What exactly are you asking?)

Comment: Sorry, ignore my poorly explained 2nd question. I got it figured out.

Comment: I don't know how it was back in 2012, but nowadays you can just add your custom `get_foo_display` method in your model definition (without reference to super) and it will be available during template rendering. Don't forget to use the `|safe tag` as you'll probably want to render html.

Answer (score 1):

Now in Django > [2.2.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.2.7/):

> Restored the ability to override get_FOO_display() (#30931).

You can override:

```py
    class FooBar(models.Model):
        foo_bar = models.CharField(_("foo"),  choices=[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')])
    
    
   
        def get_foo_bar_display(self):
            return "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

1. Override the Django `IntegerField` to make a copy of your `get_FOO_display` function:

   ```
   class MyIntegerField(models.IntegerField):
       def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False):
           super(MyIntegerField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only)
           if self.choices is not None:
               display_override = getattr(cls, 'get_%s_display' % self.name)
               setattr(cls, 'get_%s_display_override' % self.name, display_override)
   ```
2. In your class, replace your choice field with `MyIntegerField`:

   ```
   class A(models.Model):
      unit = MyIntegerField(choices=something)
   ```
3. Finally, use the copy function to return the super value:

   ```
      def get_unit_display(self, value):
          if your condition:
             return your value
          return self.get_unit_display_override()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly call `super()` because the original method doesn't "exist" yet on the parent model.

Instead, call `self._get_FIELD_display()` with the field object as its input. The field object is accessible through the `self._meta.get_field()` method.

```
def get_unit_display(self):
    singular = self._get_FIELD_display(self._meta.get_field('unit'))
    return singular + 's'
```

Answer (score -4):

You should be able to override any method on a super class by creating a method with the same name on the subclass. The argument signature is not considered. For example:

```
class A(object):
    def method(self, arg1):
        print "Method A", arg1

class B(A):
    def method(self):
        print "Method B"

A().method(True) # "Method A True"
B().method() # "Method B"
```

In the case of get_unit_display(), you do not have to call super() at all, if you want to change the display value, but if you want to use super(), ensure that you're calling it with the correct signature, for example:

```
class A(models.Model):
    unit = models.IntegerField(choices=something)

    def get_unit_display(self, value):
        display = super(A, self).get_unit_display(value)
        if value > 1:
            display = display + "s"
        return display
```

Note that we are passing value to the super()'s get_unit_display().

Comment: This would be true if it was any other regular method but get_FOO_display is created by special Django magic, like pointed in the other answer.