# Django: Pluralize choices of a Model's Field and translate them

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-i18n

I am using [Django's **i18n** mechanisms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/) to translate an app in several languages (Django 1.11).

## Situation

I have a Model with a Field takings choices:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Offer(models.Model):
    WEEK = 'week'
    MONTH = 'month'
    YEAR = 'year'
    DURATION_CHOICES = (
        (WEEK, _('week'),
        (MONTH, _('month'),
        (YEAR, _('year'),
    )
    duration = models.CharField(choices=DURATION_CHOICES, max_length=5, blank=True, null=True, \
        verbose_name=_("offer's duration"), help_text=_("Duration for which an offer, once subscribed, stays valid")
```

If I want to display this field in a template:

```
{{ counter }} remaining {{ offer.get_duration_display}}{{ counter|pluralize}}
```

Where `counter` is an integer, `offer` an Offer object. Here it works well enough because plural forms for ('week', 'month', 'year') are ('weeks', 'months', 'years'), same words with an 's' ending.

---

## Problem

Now let's say I want to translate my app to French.
This gets tricky, because the corresponding translations are ('semaine', 'moi**s**', 'année') and their plural forms are ('semaines', 'moi**s**', 'années'): **the translation for 'month' is the same in singular and plural forms**.

So what I would like to do is **defining custom plural forms for each choice in the duration Field**.

Sure enough, I could use `if` statements, but this is not elegant nor practical. So I tried to find a DRY solution.

---

## What I tried

You can easily give a plural form to a Model's name 
 with [verbose_name_plural](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural), but I didn't find anything for Fields or choices.

So I tried to use the [**`ungettext_lazy`** function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translations-and-plural), like this:

(**Edit**: so, it appears one [must not choose a custom name other than _ for gettext and consorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509160/ugettext-and-ugettext-lazy-functions-not-recognized-by-makemessages-in-python-dj))

```
from django.utils.translation import ungettext_lazy as _

class Offer(models.Model):
    WEEK = 'week'
    MONTH = 'month'
    YEAR = 'year'
    DURATION_CHOICES = (
        (WEEK, _('week', 'weeks')),
        (MONTH, _('month', 'months')),
        (YEAR, _('year', 'years')),
    )
```

`django-admin makemessages -l fr` does output those strings in the *.po file, but it doesn't work: in English, the `get_duration_display()` returns an empty string.

Anyway, I don't know how I would use it, because you can't pass parameters to the `get_FOO_display` function...

---

## Question

Would there be any way to do it? (without having to use conditional statements in my views or templates).

Do I have to override existing functions or code new ones?

I found this question ([Django: override get_FOO_display()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924985/django-override-get-foo-display)), where the answer points in an interesting direction. But this is quite tricky and I'm honestly a bit in over my head.

Can you think of another way to achieve this? Maybe an existing plugin?

Comment: what is the code for `get_duration_display()` ?

Comment: It is a Django built-in function, which is generated at runtime, as pointed out in the answer to the last linked question ([Django: override get_FOO_display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924985/django-override-get-foo-display)).
The magic happens here in the [`contribute_to_class` function (GitHub)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L704)